# Why does Visual Studio create a Debug directory when it is not the $(OutDir)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

Consider the following scenario:

```
) Create a new empty win32 console project
) Change Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Output Directory to $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
) Change Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Intermediate Directory to $(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
) Set the current configuration to Debug and Platform to Win32
) Create a main.cpp with a main function.
) Build
```

Why does visual studio create an empty `Debug` directory even though you've changed the settings to not put the output or intermediate files there? Is there any other setting you can change to eliminate that behavior?

This occurs with Visual Studio 2010-2015 AFAIK. Not sure about previous versions or 2017.